# How to obtain Real FX Balance via IBroker

Tags: ibrokers

This question is related to IBroker package.

There is a difference between `Virtual FX Position` and `Real FX Position`.

One obtains the `Virtual` positions by `twsPortfolioValue` or nested in `accDetails`

```
library(ibrokers)

tws <- twsConnect()
accDetails <- reqAccountUpdates(tws)
twsPortfolioValue(accDetails)
```

Is there a way to obtain the `Real FX` portfolio, or the `net` currency `exposures`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the cash balance in each currency you have.  This is python but I'm sure R has some way to print all the fields in accDetails, just look.

```
<updateAccountValue key=TotalCashBalance, value=1281337, currency=CAD, accountName=DU000000>
<updateAccountValue key=TotalCashBalance, value=-310, currency=USD, accountName=DU000000>
```